# Monitor Apache: Parse status page?

Tags: apache-2.2, monitoring

I want to monitor an apache server. Primary goal is to detect if MaxClients gets reached, but later other values, too.

I looked at the [nagios plugins](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Web-Servers/Apache), but most plugins seem to parse the HTML of the status page. I think this is an ugly solution. Is there any better way to get the server status?

Log file checking is *not* part of this question.

Comment: http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Web-Servers/Apache/check_apachestatus/details

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to parse HTML - Apaches mod_status is capable of producing output well-suitable for regex parsing when called with the `?auto` parameter (i.e. `http://your-server/server-status/?auto`). Depending on what monitoring system you need this to work with, there may or may not be a working / well-tested collector for this kind of thing.

As an example, take a look at how it is done in OpenNMS: https://wiki.opennms.org/wiki/Monitoring_Apache_with_the_HTTP_collector

Comment: OK, this output looks parsable.

Comment: link is 404 http://www.opennms.org/wiki/Monitoring_Apache_with_the_HTTP_collector

Answer (score 0):

You could try and compile `MOD-APACHE-SNMP` which is [here](http://mod-apache-snmp.sourceforge.net/english/docs.htm). You would use SNMP to collect your data if that is in fact an opinion for you. You can build a nice poller or use something like [MTRG](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/) to do this for you.

Personally, I like @syneticon-dj's solution better. It could be simply that i'm bias to opennms. Love the product, the support and this is the solution i use.

**NOTE** i've only heard of `MOD-APACHE-SNMP` and have not actually used it.